# shown that f is even

Tags: calculus, functions, proof-writing, functional-equations

> lets one function $f:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ where $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of reals, lets $f$ such that $f\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)=f(a)-f(b)$ for every $a$ and $b$ in belonging to the domain of f, shown that $f$ is a even function.

attempt

for $(a,b)=(x,y)\Rightarrow f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=f(x)-f(y)$

for $(a,b)=(-x,-y)\Rightarrow f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=f(-x)-f(-y)$

for $(a,b)=(-x,y)\Rightarrow f\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)=f(-x)-f(y)$

for $(a,b)=(x,-y)\Rightarrow f\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)=f(x)-f(-y)$

so we want to proof that $f(a)=f(-a)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
f\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)&=f(x)-f(y)=f(-x)-f(-y)\\
f\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)&=f(-x)-f(y)=f(x)-f(-y)
\end{align}$$

but i dont know how i can finish the proof, any hint?

Comment: What happens if you put $b = 1$? Remember, this is a function on $\mathbb{R}$. You seem to be thinking of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in what you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- First, prove that $f(1)=0$ (writing $1=\frac11$).
- Then, prove that $f(-1)=0$ (writing $-1=\frac{-1}1$ and $-1=\frac1{-1}$).
- Then, using this prove that $f(-x)=f(x)$ (writing $x-=\frac{x}{-1}$) for any $x\neq0$.

Answer (score 2):

Subtract your equations to obtain  $f(x/y)-f(-x/y)=f(x)-f(-x)=f(-x)-f(x)$